# SSh - Powershell

Tags: powershell, ssh

Can somebody help me with a script for checking if SSH is installed on a machine?

I have hundreds of PC's but I don't know which have SSH installed or not, so I want to make a script (but I don't know how) for checking this.

I can put all machines IP's in .txt.

So I think the script should look like this:

```
$ErrorActionPreference="SilentlyContinue"
Stop-Transcript | out-null
$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
Start-Transcript -path .\Check_SSH.txt -append

$Computers = Get-Content -path .\ip.txt 

# Loop through each computer in the list
foreach($Computer in $Computers){
    #Test Connection
    if ((Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $Computer -Port 22).TCPTestSucceeded){
        #Log successful connections
        Write-Host "$Computer = TRUE"
    }
    else {
        #Log unsuccessful connections
        Write-Host "$Computer = FALSE"
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance;

Comment: Are you trying to check if machines have something like OpenSSH installed? or if you can SSH to the machine?

Comment: Hello Otter ; yes, I try to verify if machine have installed OpenSSH. I install OpenSSH on many machines but I don't know witch have or not OpenSSH installed. So I need to verify somehow witch have or not OpenSSH installed. Thank you :D

Comment: The way to find if it is installed depends on the OpenSSH versions and operating systems they are installed on, what are the versions and operating systems?

Comment: I think exist a easy way.
Script;

1. Trying to connect SSH 
2. If session complete (connection complete) print in txt file IP: 10.10.10.10 - Connection OK if cannot connect print 10.10.10.1 - Connection X. ; In this case is clear ; which machine have succesful connection Have SSH ; witch not doesn't have. (no?) :D ; 

(i have win 7 ; win 10 and win XP ; for win xp I use latest version of OpenSSH for XP and  for 7 and 10 latest version of OpenSSH)

Comment: I'm only interesed if machine have or not SSH ; doesn't matter what version. Or more exaclty I'm interesed if machine can connected SSH and if succesful connected logically have SSH installed. :D

Comment: ok, so you need to know if it is listening on port 22. try using something like ```Test-NetConnection -ComputerName ComputerNameOrIPHere -Port 22``` where 'ComputerNameOrIPHere' is the computer name or IP. Let me know how far you get and i will try help from there

Comment: Yes, Thank you Otter it's a great ideea. But can I make a script to read 'ComputerNameOrIPHere' from txt and after check connection make a log with response code?

Comment: Something like that ?

# ALL IP
$ip = Get-Content -Path .\ipComputer.txt

#Test Connection
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $ip -Port 22

#Make a log with successful or not making connection
? 

Thank's a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you need to do:

```
# Get the list of computers 
$Computers = Get-Content -Path .\ipComputer.txt 

# Loop through each computer in the list
foreach($Computer in $Computers){
    #Test Connection
    if ((Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $Computer -Port 22).TCPTestSucceeded){
        #Log successful connections
    }
    else {
        #Log unsuccessful connections
    }
}
```

Comment: Can make another another .txt with return code?

10.10.10.10 - False (if not connected)
10.10.10.1 - True (if connected)

*Seems like log file

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure i understand what is required. Just remember that stackoverflow is for helping with existing code problems or questions, it is not a code writing service.

Comment: Yes, I think I solved. I edit my first topic. Thank you again :)

Only the problem is : return me all IPs with True and False

`
10.10.10.10 10.10.10.1 = TRUE
WARNING: TCP connect to 10.10.10.1:22 failed
10.10.10.10 10.10.10.1 = FALSE
`

Comment: This is because you used ```$Computers```, you should be using ```$Computer``` so ```Write-Host "$Computer = TRUE"```

Comment: *** my mind, work's fine now. Thank you again.